Exception: Those columns are out of bounds. - For-loops stops unexpected
I got this code implemented in a bigger function. Basically it searches for hidden columns to hide them in a new formed sheet that will be exported as a pdf. What happens is that at every hidden column above 30 it just stops, when columnHidden is true. Under that it just works fine.
The last to line of the logger and the error:

Info  start column: 33, left: 58 , Ende: 85 , Checking column: 33, isHidden: false
Error   Exception: Those columns are out of bounds.

So they cant be out of bounds, cause it is right in the middle of it.
const startColumn = range.getColumn();  // The starting column of the range (e.g., "E" -> 5)
const numColumns = range.getNumColumns();  // The number of columns in the range

for (let i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
  const originalColumn = startColumn + i;  // Get the original column number
  const columnHidden = sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(originalColumn);  // Check if the column is hidden in the original sheet
  const ende = tempSheet.getLastColumn();
  
  // If the column is hidden in the original sheet, hide the corresponding column in the temporary sheet
  if (columnHidden) {
    tempSheet.hideColumns(i+1);  // Hide the corresponding column in the temporary sheet
  }
  Logger.log(`start column: ${startColumn + i}, left: ${numColumns-i} , Ende: ${ende} , Checking column: ${originalColumn}, isHidden: ${columnHidden}`) ;
}

I searched for merged cells, changed the index, copy pasted. Googled it, but its not a common issue. Asked chatgpt, made a test function to see if HideColumns has a Problem with numbers above 30(it does not)...

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please share a [mre].

Based on your code, you should only replace tempSheet.hideColumns(i+1); with:
tempSheet.hideColumns(originalColumn);

Here's the code with a sample setup:
function test() {
  //sample setup
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tempSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,5,sheet.getLastRow(), sheet.getLastColumn()-4);
  var tempSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const startColumn = range.getColumn();  // The starting column of the range (e.g., "E" -> 5)
  const numColumns = range.getNumColumns();  // The number of columns in the range

  for (let i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    const originalColumn = startColumn + i;  // Get the original column number
    const columnHidden = sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(originalColumn);  // Check if the column is hidden in the original sheet
    const ende = tempSheet.getLastColumn();

    // If the column is hidden in the original sheet, hide the corresponding column in the temporary sheet
    if (columnHidden) {
      tempSheet.hideColumns(originalColumn);  // use original column here
    }
    // Logger.log(`start column: ${startColumn + i}, left: ${numColumns - i} , Ende: ${ende} , Checking column: ${originalColumn}, isHidden: ${columnHidden}`);
  }
}


Here's an alternative code using forEach and ternary operator:
function myFunction() {
  //sample setup
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var tempSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var range = sheet.getDataRange();
  var tempSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var startColumn = 5;
  //actual edits
  var data = range.getValues(); //get the 2d array data to get the dimensions for iteration
  data[0].forEach((x, i) => ((i>=startColumn)*(sheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(i + 1)) ? tempSheet.hideColumns(i + 1) : null));

}

The code above does entirely the same thing, and the code that uses forEach and ternary shortens the syntax of your code.

Reference

forEach


Better forEach reference

Both codes give back the same problem: It stops in the middle of the execution.
I changed it to deleteColumn and made some changes to the index and it worked. It seems to be a problem with the hideColumn - function.

I'm glad that you were able to modify it to cater to your needs. If my answer was useful to your question, kindly consider accepting the answer by clicking the accept button (check mark icon) on the left. You can also test the other answer by doubleunary to check if it fixes the problem.

Use Math.min(), like this:
function test() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const range = ss.getRange('Sheet1!E2:Z');
  hideSameColumns_(range.getSheet(), ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2'), range.getColumn());
}

function hideSameColumns_(sourceSheet, targetSheet, startColumn = 1) {
  const numColumns = Math.min(sourceSheet.getMaxColumns(), targetSheet.getMaxColumns()) - startColumn + 1;
  for (let i = 0; i < numColumns; i++) {
    const colNumber = startColumn + i;
    if (sourceSheet.isColumnHiddenByUser(colNumber)) targetSheet.hideColumns(colNumber);
  }
}

See Math.min().
